# How to go to Edittext when button clicked in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button

I have a layout which contains button at top and some textviews and then at bottom I have edittext.When I click button, it should point to edittext. How to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "point to edittext."?

Comment: @geet I have edittext. It is in bottom. So at the top, I placed button. when I click button, it should go to field name of Edittext ie cursor should be at edittext field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show keyboard when EditText is in focus mode.

```
 myEditText.requestFocus();
          if(myEditText.requestFocus()) {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            }
```

If you want to show some message

```
myEditText.setError("Please Enter Valid Value!");
```

You can remove message focus by Using:

```
myEditText.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

In onClick method of a button write this `edittext.requestFocus();`

Answer (score 1):

onButtonClick write below code

```
myedittext.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText)v.findViewById(your edittxt id);
            edit.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes go with requestFocus().

Inside your onClick() method write,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

          editText.requestFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private fun getKeaboardButtonListener(view: LinearLayout): View.OnClickListener {
    return View.OnClickListener {
        val  editText :EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText)
        editText.requestFocus()
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```